# Sort vectors within 2D Vectors

Tags: arrays, sorting, vector, multidimensional-array, swap

I have a problem sorting vectors in 2D vector? I would like to sort them based on their capacity from the largest to the smallest.

Example: ROWS {{1,2,3},{1,2},{1,2,3,4,5}}

it should be sorted as ROWS.capacity(); // ROWS {{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3},{1,2}}

The following is part of the code i did until now:

```
 std::vector< std::vector<int> >::iterator row;
 std::vector<int>::iterator col;



for (row=ROWS.begin(); row<ROWS.end(); row++){

Logger::logln(LOG_DEBUG, "ROW: %d",row->capacity());

     for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++){
         Logger::logln(LOG_DEBUG, " CONTENT: %d  ",*col);
     }
 }
```

i need to the following: 
       if(row1.capacity > row2.capacity)
            then swap or something like this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure you want `capacity` and not `size`?

Comment: Number of rows? 2D vector? You know, your vector is just a vector of vectors. The size of a vector is the number of elements it contains. `ROWS.size()` is the number of rows in your context and `ROWS[0].size()` is the length of the first row. `capacity` means something different. It's the number of elements you can add to th vector until it needs to reallocate its internal storage. So I think `size` should be your method of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `std::sort` with a custom ordering predicate:

```
struct CapacityGreater : public std::binary_function<std::vector<int>,
                                                     std::vector<int>,bool>
{
    bool operator()(const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b) const
        { return a.capacity() > b.capacity(); }
};

std::sort(ROWS.begin(), ROWS.end(), CapacityGreater());
```

This should work well if `std::sort` uses `std::swap` internally, otherwise the copying of rows could get quite expensive and you probably need to implement your own sorting function.

You should also think, if you really need `capacity()` and not `size()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) with custom comparison function, like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool compare(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b)
{
    return a.size() > b.size();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > v;
    // populate your vector with values here
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);
    return 0;
}
```

I used `size()` here, but if you really need `capacity()` simply change it in comparison function.

Comment: Well! I used this method but there is a problem: ERROR when calling sort ??

 error: no matching function for call to ‘sort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*, std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*, std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’